# Spring Cloud Gateway Filter ordering

Tags: filter, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using spring cloud gateway filter, and want to filter request by `GatewayFilterFactory`, 
but order not working with `@Order` annotation

I tried to swap the order of filters, but not working.

```java
@Slf4j
@Order(1)
@Component
public class AccessFilter implements GatewayFilterFactory<AccessFilter.Config> {

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(AccessFilter.Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> { 
           log.info("in AccessFilter second");
           // do something
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@Order(-1)
@Slf4j
@Component
public class AddTraceIdGlobalFilter implements GlobalFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        log.info("in globalfilter first");
        // do something
    }

}
```

My yaml file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: user_1
        uri: http://user:8080
        predicates:
        - Path=/v1/user/info
        filters:
        - AccessFilter
```

I expect the output:

```
in globalfilter first
in AccessFilter second
```

but the actual output:

```
in AccessFilter second
in globalfilter first
```

Answer (score 8):

GatewayFilterFactory cannot be applied `@Order` or `Ordered`. 
You have to use [`OrderedGatewayFilter`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/OrderedGatewayFilter.java).

```java
@Component
public class AccessFilter implements GatewayFilterFactory<AccessFilter.Config> {

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(AccessFilter.Config config) {
        return new OrderedGatewayFilter((exchange, chain) -> { 
           log.info("in AccessFilter second");
           // do something
        }, 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `Ordered` interface:

```
public class RewriteTokenGlobalPreFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered 
{
     ....

     @Override
     public int getOrder() {
        return 3;
     }
}
```